# Como remover a mensagem de error 401 do console com AngularJS/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-status

Eu recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro no meu console:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/minhaURL 401 (Unauthorized)
```

Gostaria de saber como faço pra retirar esse log de erro do console, pois já estou dando um retorno visual para o usuário de que ele errou alguma coisa.

Só pra contextualizar, estou fazendo um POST com um password, e caso o mesmo esteja incorreto, eu retorno um 401.

EDIT:

**JS**

```
    requestHandler.authenticate(password).then(function(response){
         console.log('200 ok');
    }).catch(function(err){
         console.log('401 deu erro na validação')
    });
```

Esta é mensagem de erro a qual me refiro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poste código e em qual momento isso acontece.

Comment: Ok, eu vou postar....

Comment: Acho que mesmo você tratando, o erro vai continuar sendo exibido no Console. O fato de tratar não quer dizer que o erro vai parar de ser exibido no console, mas que agora o usuário vai ter uma satisfação do que aconteceu.

Comment: Eu acho que isso não é possível por se tratar de um comportamento do browser e não do angularjs.

Comment: Eu ja me perguntei se não poderia ser isso @LucasCosta.... Mas ai queria saber se alguém tem uma saída...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não há maneira de prevenir a saída para o console.

Se você deseja forçar a limpeza completa do log, utilize

```
console.clear();
```

Entretanto isso eliminará todas as linhas, não apenas a última.

Answer (score 0):

```
.catch(function(err, status){
    if (status === 401) return;
    console.log('algo diferente de 401');
});
```

Comment: eu não quero logar uma mensagem diferente... eu só não quero que logue nada.... Eu já dou o retorno de algo deu errado no front, para o usuário

Comment: @fernandoocf, não é o caso de só remover o `console.log` ou na verdade você está procurando por outra coisa?

Comment: vou tentar postar uma imagem pra vcs

Comment: Eu quero tirar essa maldita linha... pq como se trata de um input, o usuário pode errar várias vezes e acaba enchendo o console de erros...

Comment: Não é possível. Vai aparecer e "pronto", qualquer request com status >= 400 vai aparecer ali.